# Create Generic class/method to map one object to another

Tags: java, spring, templates, generics, spring-batch

Since I'm a newbie, I would like to know if there is a better way to code this.

Let say we have batch (spring) where we have downloader/processor/mapper/writer for every type of file we receive since we have customized logic for each file type. X number of Mapper , X number of processor for X number of file types.

Currently looking into templatize the code so not much changes may be required when new type is introduced. Below is my idea. so let say mapper, we have different objects for different file types and all of them will be converted to object of Class CustomObject as below.  mapper bean in sample spring context

```
bean id = "file1Mapper" class = "com.filemapper.file1Mapper"
```

and it invokes file1Mapper class which has mapping logic. Same for other files.

This is what I'm coming up with to avoid all those file1mapper, file2mapper...... instead one generic mapper which does all together, but looking for better solutions,

```
      public class GMapper{
        public <T> CustomObject map(T item){
           CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject()
                .WithABCDetails(getABCDetails(item));
    }

    private <T> XYZDetails getABCDetails(T item) {
        ABCDetails details = new ABCDetails();
        if( item instanceof A){
            A a = (A)item;
            // read a and map it to ABCDetails object
        }
        if( item instanceof B){
            B b = (B)item;
            // read b and map it to ABCDetails object
        }
        ...
        ...
        // repeat this if loop for mapping all file types.

        return details;
    }
}
```

Sample jsons

```
    class ABCDetails{
    // JsonProperty
    Object1 ob1;
    Object2 ob2;
    Integer d;
}

class Object1{
    // JsonProperty
    Object3 ob3;
    String abc;
    String def;
}

class Object2{
    // JsonProperty
    String ab;
    Integer e;
}

class A{
    // JsonProperty
    String e;
    String d; // ex, this is mapped to Object 2 String "ab"
}
```

This does't look so professional and I believe there might be better ways to do it. Can someone please share an example or explanation on how can this code be made better. I also reading Functional interface to see if that could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking into Dozer library.  I understand moving the mapping logic to xml. but in this case, we still need to create separate xml for each file type right since each file type belong to different objects. so how is it different than existing code logic? just throwing my doubts as I'm working through. thanks!

Comment: So instead of directly mapping item to your CustomObject, you are mapping it through ABCDetails. Are they similar?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to understand what you need. So I will give some common advice.

1. Format your code - use tabs/spaces to indent.
2. Do not put capital letters together - replace ABCDetails with AbcDetails. No one cares how real world name looks like.
3. Do not write meaningless comments - say no to `// JsonProperty`
4. Name variables so that someone can understand what they are supposed to store - avoid `{Object1 ob1; Object2 ob2; Integer d;}`
5. Do not write `if ... else if ... else if ...` or `case when ...` since this scales badly. Use `Map`. Examples below.

And a general solution to your problem: use plugin architecture - the best thing (and maybe the only thing) that OOP can offer. Just make all your processors implement common interface. And to work with plugins use dispatcher pattern.

First create all processors.

```java
public interface FileProcessor {
    String extension();
    void process(String filename);
}

@Component
public final class CsvFileProcessor implements FileProcessor {
    public String extension() {
        return "csv";
    }

    public void process(String filename) {
        /* do what you need with csv */
    }
}

@Component
public final class JsonFileProcessor implements FileProcessor {
    public String extension() {
        return "json";
    }

    public void process(String filename) {
        /* do what you need with json */
    }
}
```

Then inject them into your dispatcher. Do not forget to process errors, for example, some files may not have suffix, for some files you will not have processor, etc.

```java
@Component
public final class FileDispatcher {
    private final Map<String, FileProcessor> processorByExtension;

    @Autowired
    public FileDispatcher(List<FileProcessor> processors) {
        processorByExtension = processors.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.extension(), p -> p));
    }

    public void dispatch(String filename) {
        String extension = filename.split("//.")[1];
        processorByExtension.get(extension).process(filename);
    }
}
```

Now if you need to support new file format you have to add only one class - implementation of FileProcessor. You do not have to change any of already created classes.